# How to handle Node.js http server timeout event?

Tags: node.js, http

I have a HTTP server that will always result in HTTP timeout, e.g.

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('OK');
    res.end();
  }, 2000);
});
server.setTimeout(1000);
server.on('timeout', (socket) => {
  // How to produce a custom HTTP response here?
});
```

HTTP server "timeout" event is emitted with `socket` reference. How do I use `socket` to encode HTTP response?

I know that I can stitch the response myself at a low-level, e.g.

```
server.on('timeout', (socket) => {
  socket.write([
    'HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout',
    'Connection: close'
  ].join('\n') + '\n\n');

  socket.end();
});
```

But is there a way to use the HTTP response interface, i.e. `writeHead`/ `write`/ `end`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback) function on the response object. Consider this simple example:

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;

const requestHandler = (req, res) => {
    res.setTimeout(Math.random() * 2500, () => {
        res.writeHead(408);
        res.end();
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (res.headersSent) {
            return;
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write('OK');
        res.end();
    }, 2000);
};

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('an error happened', err)
    }
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
});
```

If you call `localhost:3000` in your web browser you'll now either see 200 OK or a 408 error. Note that you'll need to handle already sent headers if the random timeout was less than 2000 ms.